# Azure ML: How do we connect to registered dataset (made out of SQL datastore) in python script?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using Azure ML. Have created a datastore from Azure SQL database. 
Then registered a dataset using SQL from this datastore.

Able to view data in the dataset, but when trying to read this dataset from a python script, I get the error as below:

> *"Exception=DatasetExecutionError; Could not connect to specified database"*

Below is the sample code:

```
dataset = Dataset.get_by_name(workspace=ws, name='ds_test')
df_rawest = (dataset.to_pandas_dataframe())
```

- Where:

  ---
- **`ds_test = my registered dataset`**
- **`and ws = Azure workspace`**

Has anybody faced such issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below snapshots and the following [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-create-register-datasets) to register dataset.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Ram for your solution. I tried to fetch the data from my registered datastore as per your approach, but again facing the same issue.

Comment: When I try to run the below code:  `datastore = Datastore.get(ws, 'datastore_test)
        query = DataPath(datastore, 'SELECT GETDATE()')
        tabular = Dataset.Tabular.from_sql_query(query)
        xx = tabular.to_pandas_dataframe()
        print(xx.head(3))` . I am getting the below error:  "azureml.data.dataset_error_handling.DatasetValidationError: Cannot load any data from the datastore using the SQL query "{}". Please make sure the datastore and query is correct."

Comment: Dataset team is fixing this bug.You can also raise an issue here (https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues).

Comment: Thanks Ram. I have also raised the same on the mentioned github page. Issue#716.